# AWS Cognito authenticate different lambda functions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I've currently implemented a cognito user pool for my app and used it on the api-gateway to secure my functions. Its all working well, but here's my problem. I have 2 lambda functions: `CreateEmployee` and `DeleteEmployee`. How can I set that only specific users has access to the `DeleteEmployee` function?

Comment: May be this helps https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Add custom authorizer and in api getway add in authorizer. 
Inside custom authorizer lambda add ur logic to allow denied access as per your requirements .

Answer (score 0):

You can use user groups to assign different roles to different group of users. Create two roles one with delete access and one without. Now add users to groups as you require.

You can find the details of group based role access here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/

Comment: But in the Authorizer section of API Gateway we can choose only the user pool right?. Is there any way to choose User Group?

Comment: You don't need to choose user group. Depending on which user logs in role is selected for him (since user belongs to group)

Comment: Okay I understand. This is a good answer for the problem then.

Comment: thanks for the reply guys. ill try this. thank you so much